# 64 bit windows 10 pro visual studio and oracle 64 bit - error that oracle is not 64 bit

Tags: visual-studio-2015, oracle11g, visual-studio-2017

I need to connect an oracle database to a C# application, whenever I test connection I get an error saying "Attempt to load Oracle client libraries threw BadImageFormatExceptio. This problem will occur when running in 64 bit mode with the 32 bit Oracle client components installed."

I am 100% sure that I have Oracle 11g 64 bit installed.
I am 100% sure that I have windows 10 pro 64 bit.
I thought I was sure that I had a 64 bit visual studio, but after some inspection and research it seems that there is no "64 bit" visual studio.

Could it be that the problem is actually having a 64 bit version of Oracle 11g installed ? if not, any suggestions on how to fix this problem ?

I tried all the solutions I could find online, and I tried adding the data source in visual studio 2015 and 2017.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this problem through installing oracle 11g express 32 bit along with normal oracle 11g 64 bit, I have no idea what caused this issue as everything should have worked fine in 64 bit.

Comment: Most likely your process is 32-bit.